# Stripe reactjs - could not find elements context

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am working on a ReactJS project where I want to integrate stripe to allow users to update their payment information for a subscription.

I am following the guide at https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react but I am hitting an issue.

Below is the code that I currently have

```
const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const errorDialogueCleared = () => {
        setAPIResult(null);
    }

    const stripePromise = loadStripe('my_test_key');

    const baseStripeElementOptions = {
        style: {
            base: {
                fontFamily: 'Oxanium',
                fontSize: '16px',
                    color: '#000000',
                    '::placeholder': {
                    color: '#000000',
                },
            },
            invalid: {
                color: '#9e2146',
            },
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        // Block native form submission.
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            // Stripe.js has not loaded yet. Make sure to disable
            // form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
            return;
        }

        // Get a reference to a mounted CardElement. Elements knows how
        // to find your CardElement because there can only ever be one of
        // each type of element.
        const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

        // Use your card Element with other Stripe.js APIs
        const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
        });

        if (error) {
            console.log('[error]', error);
        } else {
            console.log('[PaymentMethod]', paymentMethod);
        }
    };

    return (

        <div className='container-fluid'>

            <div className="mainContentNoSidebar">

                <TopNavBar displayTimePeriodButton={false} title='Update Account Information' />

                <BreadcrumbNav menu_items={breadcrumbNav} />

                <div className='contentWrapper'>

                    <div className='container'>
                        <h1>Update Account Information</h1>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{width: '50%', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'}}>
                            <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                                <CardElement options={baseStripeElementOptions} />
                            </Elements>

                            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit Payment Details</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

            <ErrorDialogue dialogClosed={errorDialogueCleared} api_result={currentError} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

However, although it feels like I've followed the documentation I am getting the following error as soon as the page loads:

> Error: Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of
> your app that calls useStripe() in an  provider

My `CardElement` is wrapped in an `Elements` components so I'm not sure why I am seeing this error.

Comment: if your FOLDER name is PAGES, then it will trigger this bug. Here is video with proof: https://youtu.be/UAYJwUpbngA, so move ALL of your components that are stripe to COMPONENTS folder and it will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I fetch the client secret in Stripe Reactjs and why can't I render a payment form without it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919950/how-can-i-fetch-the-client-secret-in-stripe-reactjs-and-why-cant-i-render-a-pay)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot call `useElements` unless you're already have the correct stripe context.

This means that your whole component you're showing here should be wrapped by `Elements` and not just the `CardElement`.

It should like this:

```
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripePromise = loadStripe('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_API_KEY');

const Wrapper = (props) => (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <MyComponent {...props} />
  </Elements>
);

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  // rest of the component
};
```

Comment: As in I should have ```return (<Elements>...Code from my component JSX from question</Elements>``` as I've tried this and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Ah I think I know what you mean, its not wrapped in the specific components, its wrapped in the App return not the individual components return

Comment: Looks like its working now. Thanks for the the help. Had to wrap the `<Elements>` tag around the content within App.js whereas I was only doing it within the component where I wanted the payment form.

Comment: I faced this error when trying to migrate from `react-stripe-elements`. I had mistakenly imported `Elements` from that deprecated package instead of `react-stripe-js`

Answer (score 2):

Just put your component into a Parent Component, which is wrapped in the Elements Tag:

```
import React from "react";
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'

const ParentComponent= () => (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <ChildComponent />
  </Elements>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that folder name is NOT pages, but components... otherwise `<Elements>` wrapper will bug and say that it is not there.

if your FOLDER name is PAGES, then it will trigger this bug, so move ALL of your components that are stripe to COMPONENTS folder or any other folder name other than PAGES and it will work