# how can I fetch the client secret in Stripe Reactjs and why can't I render a payment form without it?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, checkout

I followed the basic react stripe documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react

So here is my problematic code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe('process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY');

function Index() {
/*     const options = {
        // passing the client secret obtained from the server
        clientSecret: '{{CLIENT_SECRET}}',
      }; */
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} /* options={options} */>
      <App/>
      
    </Elements>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**checkout.tsx**

```
import {PaymentElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import React from 'react';

export default function CheckoutForm  () {
  return (
    <form>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Error with the client secret option commented out:

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: In order to create a payment element, you must pass a valid PaymentIntent or SetupIntent client secret when creating the Elements group.

  e.g. stripe.elements({clientSecret: "{{CLIENT_SECRET}}"})
```

The error with the option uncommented is basicalyl that CLIENT_SECRET is undefined or not the proper format.

I have noticed in the video tutorial from Stripe, the guy is just fine without the option but I cannot reproduce it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5y5WwF9s-ZI&t=356s

Generally speaking the documentation does not say how nor when to get the CLIENT_SECRET variable  anyways.

Comment: Well u need to get rid of the quotes around the env variable cause now ur just passing a string. It should be loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY); assuming u have this env variable available for the terminal it should work.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how you fetch the client secret from server, but you must ensure `<Elements>`is furnished with a correct client secret (i.e. cannot be empty) on its initial render.

Try adding `clientSecret &&` before `<Elements>`, just like [this example](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) (choose 'Web' and 'React' to see sample code in React) in the official docs:

```
export default function App() {
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }] }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setClientSecret(data.clientSecret));
  }, []);

  const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe',
  };
  const options = {
    clientSecret,
    appearance,
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {clientSecret && (
        <Elements options={options} stripe={stripePromise}>
          <CheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This ensure `<Elements>` won't be mounted if clientSecret is falsy (i.e. false, undefined or null).

Answer (score 4):

Migrating from CardElement to PaymentElement can be a pain in the ass if you try to follow stripe documentation. Your case may be different but if is there anyone trying to migrate from CardElement to PaymentElement, there are some points to note.

Most of the time problem is the price you want to charge is not constant. So, you have to make a post request to get clientSecret for each payment request. Since you normally don't use app.js for making such a request you separate your payment component (ideally with a different URL such as yourapp/payment etc.).  It works fine with CardElement, you can create a payment.js component and wrap it with Elements by just passing  stripe={stripePromise}. However, if you want to use PaymentElement in Payment.js. Then you also have to pass options={options}. Options constant have the clientSecret value inside of it which you also have to clarify beforehand. If you don't then it just doesn't work. If you try to wrap it with "{ clientSecret && " as suggested by the top comment, then you cant see the payment.js in clientside since you don't have the clientSecret. Stripe requires clientSecret to have an appropriate value.

Stripe created a chicken-and-egg problem here, if I can't get into the Payment component How am I going to get the clientSecret that is needed for payment.js to work? Because, if payment.js doesn't work then I can't make a post request and I can't get the clientSecret.

The solution to the problem is you have to create 1 more component. app.js, payment.js, and checkout.js. Anything stripe documentation recommends for you to make in app.js will be done in payment.js. All the logic, price calculation, etc. will be in payment.js. You will keep checkout.js as same as in the documentation. Then, "Bob's your uncle"

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the quotes around the env variable cause now ur just passing a string. It should be loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY); assuming u have this env variable available for the terminal it should work.

Credit to @blessanm86

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. The suggestion posted by @oğuz-gürkan-bilir -- of wrapping the component containing `<PaymentElement>` with a parent component containing `<Elements>` -- worked for me.

I modified [this Stripe example on github](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/main/fixed-price-subscriptions/client/react/src) which is the React version of [this vanilla JS tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements).

Here are my final modified React components:

- [Register.js](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/main/fixed-price-subscriptions/client/react/src/Register.js) [no modifications]
- [Prices.js](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/main/fixed-price-subscriptions/client/react/src/Prices.js) [no modifications]
- Checkout.js (added this component to hold the `<Elements>` component)

```
const Checkout = ({location}) => {

    const fetchStripePromise = async () => {
        const {publishableKey} = await fetch('/app-config').then(r => r.json());
        return loadStripe(publishableKey);
    };

    // Get the lookup key for the price from the previous page redirect.
    const [clientSecret] = useState(location.state.clientSecret);
    const [stripePromise, setStripePromise] = useState(async () => await fetchStripePromise())

    return (<div>
        {clientSecret && stripePromise && (<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{clientSecret}}>
            <Subscribe/>
        </Elements>)}
    </div>);
}
export default withRouter(Checkout);
```

- Subscribe.js (modified from [Subscribe.js](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/main/fixed-price-subscriptions/client/react/src/Subscribe.js))

```
const Subscribe = ({location}) => {
    const [messages, _setMessages] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    // helper for displaying status messages.
    const setMessage = (message) => {
        _setMessages(`${message}`);
    }

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const result = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements, redirect: "if_required", confirmParams: {
                return_url: `${window.location.origin}/account`,
            }
        });

        if (result.error) {
            // show error and collect new card details.
            setMessage(result.error.message);

        } else {
            history.push("/account");
        }
    }

    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <PaymentElement/>
            <button>
                Subscribe
            </button>
         </div>
     </form>
    );

}

export default withRouter(Subscribe);
```

- [Account.js](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/blob/main/fixed-price-subscriptions/client/react/src/Account.js) [no modifications]